# Show A Custom Field from Similar Category (Getting A Custom Field from Similar Posts)

Tags: wordpress

I have a single.php where I display a Product. I have Category and Sub Categories for this product and I want to display a the bottom a custom field image from similar categories.

For Example I'm in **Red Bag 1**, I want to put in the bottom a **thumbnail** of similar pages like **Red Bag 2** and **Red Bag 3** which are in the same category "Red Bag"

I actually have a code already but I don't know how to target the custom field created by Advance Custom Field plugin: `the_field("product_image")`

here's my code:

```
              <?php
            global $post;
            $cat_ID=array();
            $categories = get_the_category(); //get all categories for this post
              foreach($categories as $category) {
                array_push($cat_ID,$category->cat_ID);
              }
              $args = array(
              'orderby' => 'date',
              'order' => 'DESC',
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'numberposts' => 8,
              'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
              'category__in' => $cat_ID
              ); // post__not_in will exclude the post we are displaying
                $cat_posts = get_posts($args);
                $out='';


                  foreach($cat_posts as $cat_post) {
                      $out .= '<li>';
                      $out .=  '<a href="'.get_permalink($cat_post->ID).'" title="'.wptexturize($cat_post->post_title).'">'.wptexturize($cat_post->post_title).'</a></li>';
                  }
                $out = '<ul class="cat_post">' . $out . '</ul>';
                echo $out;
            ?>
```

where `.wptexturize($cat_post->post_title).` suppose to be an image instead of the title. The image source should be taken from the custom field `the_field("product_image")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would use [`post_thumbnail_html`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) it would be a lot simpeler. Instead you use a a function which is not default to wordpress: `the_field`.
I don't know which plugin does this.

Probably that function (`the_field`) would work within a normal [`loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/the_loop).
To do that you should change `get_posts($args)` to `WP_Query($args)` and replace the `foreach($cat_posts..` with a loop.

I advise to use the default wordpress thumbnail/featured image with `post_thumbnail_html`

Comment: That makes sense. I use the_field for Advance Custom Fields Plugin and yes I don't see the point in using that against the featured image. Thanks for the suggestion and I will try this.

Comment: hi, if I use post_thumbnail instead, how can I output it?

`.wptexturize($cat_post->post_thumb).` doesnt work